# XWindow + OpenGL, cant compile files

Tags: c++, opengl, x11

I want to compile my OpenGL + Xwindow C++ program, but I am getting errors:

```
g++: fatal error: no input files
compliation terminated.
./source/Linux_OpenGL.c: line 10: //: is catalogue
...typedef: command not found
...Bool command not found
...XSetWindowAttributes command not found
...Syntax error near '}'.
```

and so on...

This is my compile script:

```
$(g++ -Wall -pedantic -ansi) ./source/Linux_OpenGL.cpp ./source/render.cpp -o Linux_OpenGL -lX11 -lGL -lGLU -lXxf86vm
```

How can I successfully compile my program?

Answer (score 2):

Well I'd start by not doing this: `$(g++ -Wall -pedantic -ansi)`

This is telling the shell:

> "interpret the output of *`g++ -Wall -pedantic -ansi`* as script and execute it".

This is definitely not what you want.

Use just

```
g++ -Wall -pedantic -ansi ./source/Linux_OpenGL.cpp ./source/render.cpp -o Linux_OpenGL -lX11 -lGL -lGLU -lXxf86vm
```